# Set innerText to a variable but it doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm tring to code a tic tac toe game by using buttons, and in my plan I want to store a button.innertext to be a variable so that I can use it to make the judgement of game result more convinient. Here's the code, for simplicity, I only put one button here

```
const b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
const b = [b1];
let b1T = b1.innerText;
let xo = true;
show();
function show() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    b[i].addEventListener("click",go)
  }
}
//decide x or o is displayed
function go(event) {
  if(xo) {
    event.target.innerText = "X";
    event.target.disabled = true;
    xo = false; 
  } else {
    event.target.innerText = "O";
    event.target.disabled = true;
    xo = true;
  }
}
function decide() {
if(b1T === "X"){
//do something
}
}
```

When I tried to write the part in function decide, I noticed that b1T didn't change it's value to "X" or "O", by console.log(b1T) I only got empty like I setted in HTML file `<button id = "b1"><button>`, but when I typed console.log(b1.innerText) it did show the innerText of it. Am I settig the biT variable in the wrong place or something else?

Comment: Are you executing your JavaScript code after all html elements are rendered?

Comment: yes, I think the problem is that I should declare the b1T inside the function, not the outside. Thanks

Comment: An assignment like `b1T = b1.innerText;` does not extend into the future, it will set the variable on the left exactly once, at the time it is executed, then never again, unless it is executed again.

Comment: I didn't notice that before, thanks for replying me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the text from your button inside the `decide` function instead. Your button is changing it's inner text when you press it, so you need to get the latest text (not the oldest one).

```
function decide() {
 const b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
 if(b1.innerText === "X"){
  //do something
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening  because the code on line number 2, i.e.
**let b1T = b1.innerText**
is run only during page load. You need to set that again to either "X" or "O" when handling the click events.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is code error inside show(). ReferenceError: Can't find variable: b
2. Once above issue is fixed and b[i] is replaced with b1, its working fine.

Please check below code snippet.

```js
const b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let b1T = b1.innerText;
let xo = true;
show();
function show() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    b1.addEventListener("click",go)
  }
}
//decide x or o is displayed
function go(event) {
  if(xo) {
    event.target.innerText = "X";
    event.target.disabled = true;
    xo = false; 
  } else {
    event.target.innerText = "O";
    event.target.disabled = true;
    xo = true;
  }
}
function decide() {
if(b1T === "X"){
//do something
}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="b1">Click</button>
</body>
```

Let me know if this is what expected.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put `const b = [b1]` inside my example code, thanks for correcting me, it works well!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a dc variable to record how many buttons are pressed, and put the function decide() into function go(), and declare b1T inside the function decide() so that everytime I click the button it will update all the variables that store button.innertext.
Here's the code:

```
const b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let b1T = b1.innerText;
let dc = 0;
let xo = true;
show();
function show() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    b1.addEventListener("click",go)
  }
}
//decide x or o is displayed
function go(event) {
  if(xo) {
    event.target.innerText = "X";
    event.target.disabled = true;
dc += 1;
    xo = false; 
  } else {
    event.target.innerText = "O";
    event.target.disabled = true;
dc+= 1;
    xo = true;
  }
decide();
}
function decide() {
let b1T = b1.innerText;
   if(dc >= 5) {
    if(b1T === "X"){
     //do something
      }
   }
}
```

Thank all you guys' efforts